# RazorEngine v2.1 throwing "Object is null" exception on Razor.Parse

Tags: razorengine

My Template looks like this:

```
@using RazorEngine;
@model System.String
@{
    var content = @"<div id=""text-block-container"">
            @Html.Raw(""<h1>test</h2>"")
    </div>";
    Razor.SetTemplateBase(typeof(MvcTemplateBase<>));

    var output = Razor.Parse<MyType>(content, new MyType() );
}
<div>
    @Html.Raw(output)
</div>
```

The MvcTemplateBase looks like:

```
public abstract class MvcTemplateBase<T> : TemplateBase<T> {
    public HtmlHelper<object> Html { get; private set; }
    public UrlHelper Url { get; private set; }

    public void InitHelpers() {
        var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        var handler = httpContext.CurrentHandler as MvcHandler;
        if (handler == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to run template outside of ASP.NET MVC");
    }
```

Edited title: I figured out what was causing the "Clear" not defined error. I had my own version of TemplateBase defined and that was the version that was namespaced into this. Since I didn't define a Clear method in my implementation that caused the error.

Now I'm getting a null exception on the Razor.Parse call even though the inputs are not null, both 'raw' and the supplied model are initialized and have values.

Edited to correct minor coding error in example.

Answer (score 1):

The `MvcTemplateBase<T>` type is not yet developed, and the version you are currently using is a very early unfinished version.

I would question why you are trying to run a RazorEngine template within an MVC Razor view?

Comment: I'm not actually running this from an MVC application. This is a dynamically compiled template to generate emails and messages from back-end services. I am thinking about reconsidering this and just deploying a separate MVC Messaging Application to handle this as a service.

Comment: But my question would be, why are you trying to run a template from within a template? The `MvcTemplateBase<T>` type is designed to be an MVC-compatible template type, to be used in an MVC environment.

Comment: Well I started to answer with a long detailed "I'm not doing that ... this is what I'm doing." The short answer is I'm not actually doing that. This code no longer exists in my code base. I'm guessing this was a question posted on a research spike I was doing. I have resolved the issue I was trying to solve without any of this code. The problem was trying solve at the time was I needed to insert essentially static html from a database into a template. This feature allows customers to configure certain aspects of the content with in a page specific to their site deployment.